# How to replace scripts in WordPress with the ones from CDN?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am newbie of wordpress.

There are always some JS and Css from CDN in Wordpress, theme or plugins, like:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.0/webfont.js

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Unfortunately, those external CDNs resource are quite slow in our country, and will caused our site serious delay.

Is there anyway to replace it with a local server copy please?

How should I do it please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/295240/loading-jquery-locally?

Answer (score 0):

One solution you got in comments that how to load jQuery locally and in case you have any other scripts or styles which are not available locally by default from WordPress so you can use [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/%60).

/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
*/

function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );`

Comment: Hello, I do not understant what does '1.0.0" mean, would you please clarify? thanks

Comment: Sure, we can manage versions of the script here as a parameter. At the moment, it's static, 1.0.0 and you can use any variable instead. Sometimes we have dynamic files return the script from same source. 

e.g. xyz.com/scripts.php?ver=1.0.0

so this file can respond different on different versions, like this

e.g. xyz.com/scripts.php?ver=1.0.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I add your code line by the plugin of Code Snippets as the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/mpb5ez, but it not work: http://prntscr.com/mpb5n3. By the way, our server is in China, and we are blocked to access Google public resource, and that is reason why I need replace it by local copy.

Comment: Make sure that you are not missing this line after your functions,

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );

Comment: Hi, thanks. I test this: http://prntscr.com/mptsab

but it still not work.http://prntscr.com/mptu74

This plugin works for us:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/useso-take-over-google/

it will replace google resource by a China local CDN resource, unfortunately, it not relpace jquery-ui.css in other plugins, and also there are some error message if enable debug in wp-config.php. it was out of update for 3 years, and there are not respond from the author. Maybe I ask where I should as volunteer

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always override your current themeto enqueue your css and js. Basically go to :

> wordpress/wp-content/themes/(the theme your using)/functions.php

You will need to modify the "functions.php" file and add an action in order to enqueue your new scripes and styles.

```
function mynew_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('webfont', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.0/webfont.js');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');

//And for local file use get_template_directory_uri() to get the path
wp_enqueue_script('yourjsfile',get_template_directory_uri().'/yourthemedir/assets/js/yourjsfile.js');
wp_enqueue_style('yourcssfile',get_template_directory_uri().'/yourthemedir/assets/js/yourcssfile.css');


}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mynew_scripts');
```

check up these functions [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) , [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Comment: thanks, which directory I should input "mynew_scripts" please?  but really do not understand this way, does that mean fallback to the local copy if CDNs failed? thanks

Comment: if yes, that does not what I want, I just want to replace it with local copy since the CDNS is completely unreachable to us, thanks

Comment: Hi @Li Alex according to the usual guides each Wordpress theme has a folder named assets with two subfolders Js and Css, so you copy your local scripts to these folders : wordpress/wp-content/themes/(the theme your using)/Assets/Js . Glad it helped please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you :)

Comment: you put your local copy in your assets folder and you enqueu them with proper wordpress function, if you want cdn you can do it same way two. Also check up add_action and priority arg might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, @aness, I am not technical background, but I can access those wordpress files by Sftp, may I ask you send me a instance to put into function.php of CHILD THEME, OR by the plugin of Code Snippets?

Comment: Alterntively, I found there is CDN in our country which is much stable than Google resource,http://staticfile.org,  it would be great if you could help me with loading these JS locally and that CDN resource, thanks in Advance.

Comment: but I prefer load it from local server.

Comment: Hello @Aness here is I input:



function mynew_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('webfont', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.0/webfont.js');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');

//And for local file use get_template_directory_uri() to get the path
wp_enqueue_script('yourjsfile',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/webfont.js');
wp_enqueue_style('yourcssfile',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/jquery-ui.css');


}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mynew_scripts');

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, and please check the screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/moqtfg

the errors are same in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

I am sure put those Js and CSS into the JS and CSS directory, please check the screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/moqv0n

any other way to suggestion?

Comment: Hi @Li Alex saw your screenshot try changing to (http) CHANGE https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.0/webfont.js TO http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.0/webfont.js . If it works that means that you will need to check your hosting and maybe add an SSL free letsencrypt certificate in order to use https & tweak your apache or nginx

Comment: lets encrypt certificate is already working before I input those code lines.